# How do I use @discordjs/voice AudioPlayer methods across modules?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I am adding a music-playing feature to my bot using @discordjs/voice, following the voice guide on discordjs.guide. My slash commands are all stored on different files. I want to use the pause method of the AudioPlayer class outside of play.js.

The relevant parts of play.js are:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { StreamType, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('play')
        .setDescription('An example of the play command.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({ channelId: interaction.member.voice.channel.id, guildId: interaction.guild.id, adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator });
        
        const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw', { filter: 'audioonly' });
        const resource = createAudioResource(stream, { inputType: StreamType.Arbitrary });
        const player = createAudioPlayer();
        
        player.play(resource);
        
        connection.subscribe(player);
        
        await interaction.reply('Playing.');
    },
};
```

and of pause.js are:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('pause')
        .setDescription('An example of the pause command.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        player.pause();

        await interaction.reply('Paused.');
    },
};
```

My console got the following error when I ran the /pause command after I tried to export player from player.js and require it in pause.js:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pause')
```

What do I need to do to use player.pause() outside of play.js?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [this](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html) part of the Discord.js guide, in the Access part. The `getVoiceConnection` method serves this purpose.
It allows you to use the connection created in *play.js* anywhere in your code. Then, you just need to change the state of the player with `connection.state.subscription.player.pause()`.
I did my *pause.js* by checking whether the member using the pause command is in a channel and if he is, whether the bot is in it or not:

```js
    if (!interaction.member.voice.channelId) {
        return interaction.reply('not in a channel.');
    }
    const connection = getVoiceConnection(interaction.member.voice.channel.guildId);
    if (!connection || (connection.joinConfig.channelId != interaction.member.voice.channelId)) {
        return interaction.reply('The bot is not in this channel.');
    }
    connection.state.subscription.player.pause();
    await interaction.reply('Paused.');
```

[discord.js](/questions/tagged/discord.js)